# AVURLAsset returns duration as 0

Tags: ios, audio, duration, avurlasset

I am trying to get the duration of the audio files for trimming them, I am using the below code,

```
audioAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:itemURL];

CMTime assetTime = [audioAsset duration];
Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(assetTime);
```

when I provide itemURL of any audio file of media library, I get the proper duration, and then I am able to trim the audio file. Then I save the trimmed audio file in document directory. But when I try to trim the already trimmed file the same code returns me 0 as duration. However I am able to play  the trimmed file and get the duration using AVAudioPlayer, but what is the problem with AVURLAsset I am not able to figure out.

Can anyone help? 
I have already tried almost all the answers of such question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 23):

Probably you have used

```
  NSURL *itemPathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:outPath];
```

instead of

```
NSURL *itemPathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outPath];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `AVURLAsset` needs to know the type extension of your file to compute its duration.
You're probably storing your file as `{fileName}` and not as `{fileName}.{extension}`.

If you run the following code with `yourFileName` without extension you get `*** Could not find format reader for URL`, and return value 0.

```
import AVFoundation

let fileName = *yourFileName*
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
println(asset.duration.value.description)
```

Comment: I came across a similar problem when opening a local file. My solution was to include a asset.init() after 'asset = AVURLAsset(...)' The duration was then populated with the correct length of the movie.  I'm writing in C# so there might be differences. But I landed on this topic while trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> For Swift 3.0 and above

import AVFoundation

```
  let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: ("Your File Path here")!))
  let totalSeconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))
  let minutes = totalSeconds / 60
  let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
  let mediaDuration = String(format:"%02i:%02i",minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: You can also use asset.duration.seconds

Answer (score 1):

for my case, the filename's extension have to be recognized, like ".mp3".
if not, it will return 0.

...
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filefullname), options: nil)
... asset.duration ...

Answer (score 0):

Try like following.....

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask,   YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getAudioPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"song.mp3"];
NSURL *finalUrl=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:getAudioPath];
NSLog(@"finalUrl===%@",finalUrl);
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: finalUrl];
duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
NSLog(@"duration==%f",duration);
```

Comment: Yes the same thing I am trying the first part of your code is in another method in my case and there I am getting the URL just like you did, so that's not the prblem.

Answer (score -3):

Try this....

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:Yoururl options:nil];
CMTime time = asset.duration;
double durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
int minutes = floor(durationInSeconds/60);
int seconds = round(durationInSeconds - (minutes * 60));
NSString * duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i",minutes,seconds];
NSLog(@"Duration : %@", duration);
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? He said that the duration was 0. Formatting it into minutes and seconds makes absolutely no difference at all.